# using Java mouseClicked event handler to change icons

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouselistener, imageicon

I have tons of labels. My problem is that I don't know how to write that if i click `label2`, then set a new image on `label2` but `label1` doesnt change. labels are named like A1-A10. (I actually have 92 labels, so this is getting cumbersome.) Here's my code:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {

    if (event.getSource()==A1 && (x==1)) {
        A1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("zoldgomb.jpg"));
        x=2;
    } else if(x==2) {
        A1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("sargagomb.jpg"));
        x=1;
    }
}
```

### **edit**

ok, i solved it, thx everybody :)

```
if (event.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {
                if (x == 1) {
                    ((JLabel)event.getSource()).setIcon(new ImageIcon("zoldgomb.jpg"));
                    x = 2;
                } else if (x == 2) {
                    ((JLabel)event.getSource()).setIcon(new ImageIcon("sargagomb.jpg"));
                    x = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It sounds like you should be using either an array or ArrayList of JLabel.
2. Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Also you should avoid using trivial variable names such as `b` or `s` unless they are being used for trivial purposes such as the index of a for loop. Instead use names that have some meaning so that your code becomes self-commenting.
3. You can identify which JLabel was pressed by calling `getSource()` on the MouseEvent objevct passed into your method. Your parameter is named `event` above.
4. Then after testing which JLabel is pressed, call its `setIcon(...)` method.
5. You're better off reading in your images once and saving them to a variable, and not re-reading them in on each mouse click.

Comment: +1 for using `getSource()` so a common listener can be shared by all labels.

Comment: @user3633989: you will advance from beginner to intermediate **much** quicker if you try to first write it yourself. Then if stuck come back with your code and your specific questions. Also for future questions, you should never ask folks here to write code for you. That's not how this place works, and can upset some of the volunteers here. While we'll be happy answering questions and providing directions, ultimately the problem is yours, the code should be yours.

Comment: @user3633989 don't post code in comments as it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23712290/edit). Also, to get the best help, consider creating and posting a [minimal example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.